# Is there a criterion for a system of two linear equations with real coefficients to have integer solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you are given the system $$ a_1 x + b_1 y = c_1$$ $$a_2 x + b_2 y = c_2$$, with real coefficients. Is there a criterion for the existence of an integer solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using Cramer formulas $x=\dfrac{D_x}{D},x=\dfrac{D_y}{D}$ :

$D_x$ and  $D_y$ have both to be integer multiples of $D.$

(see "Applications" in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)).